# 動画を端末から選択し、その動画の再生時間によって選択できないようにしたい

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

私は今[こちらのサイト](https://off.tokyo/blog/swift3-video-disp-how/)を参考にしながら自分の端末から動画を引っ張ってくる処理を作成しています。

私はこの処理に加えて動画の再生時間が1分を超えるものは選択できないようにしたいのですが、どのようにすれば解決するでしょうか

ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

動画の再生時間を取得するコードは以下のようになっています

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
       
        var duration: String = ""        // 再生時間

        videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? URL
        imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //ビデオの再生時間取得
        let video = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL!)
        let durationTime = TimeInterval(round(Float(video.duration.value) / Float(video.duration.timescale)))


    }
```

Comment: 「こちらのサイト」のコードは(deprecatedとなった)`UIImagePickerController`を使った、かなり古いものですね。ただ、古い`UIImagePickerController`にしろ、新しい`PHPickerViewController`にしろ、ファイルサイズで選択できる範囲を絞り込む機能は無かったと思います。「一旦自由に選択させてから、ユーザにダメ出しをして再選択させる」か、もしくは「動画の一覧を`UIImagePickerController`風に表示して選択できるような画面を自作する」必要があるだろうと思います。「私の知る限りは」で、「そんな方法は無い」と言う回答を書けるほど自信がないので、もしかしたら私の知らない新しい方法があるかもしれませんが。そういった制限をつけたいと言う要望はポツポツ見つかったので、探せばサードパーティ製のライブラリで所望のものがあるかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど、とても丁寧に回答していただきありがとうございます。